# Ruby on Rails favoriting controller & syntax problems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, syntax, favorites

I'm creating a "destroy" method in my favorites_controller. Not sure how I should express the commented-out requirement below, asking to find the current user's favorite with the ID in the params. I know I'm close but my current knowledge of ruby syntax is not up to par yet. An "undefined method `favorite' for #" error pops up and points to the [initialized?] 'favorite' variable line below when I use the unfavorite function of my app. Please help. Thank you!

```
def destroy
    # Get the post from the params
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    # Find the current user's favorite with the ID in the params
    favorite = current_user.favorite.find(params[:id]) 
    if favorite.destroy
      flash[:notice] = "Post was succesfully un-favorited"
      redirect_to @post 
      # Flash success and redirect to @post
    else
      flash[:error] = "There was an error in un-favoriting this post"
      redirect_to @post
      # Flash error and redirect to @post
    end
  end
```

Comment: Can you please tell us relation between user and favourite i guess it's has_many if that is the case then you should use `current_user.favorites`

Comment: Thank you Anant! It worked! the comment below us though, answered earlier so I gave him the credit. Hope that's okay.

Comment: no worry i will still put my answer below may be it might help someone else :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming the User can have many Favorites, since you're attempting to single one out via `params[:id]`. If that's the case, try changing `.favorite` to `.favorites`.

Hope that solves it!

Answer (score 0):

I guess relation between user and favourite is has_many so in that case you should use 
`current_user.favorites`